# No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Spring data JPA with snowflake. Even though I have passed warehouse in url but getting below exception while fetching records:

**Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.**

**Below is my application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:snowflake://domain.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=db_name&warehouse=warehouse_name&role=role_name

spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=Abcd#1

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema_name
```

Please let me know if anyone needs entity class and jpa repository code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warehouse parameter is misspelled in you URL string.  `werehouse` should be `warehouse`.

Also - you can set a default warehouse for any user, so you won't get the above error:
`alter user <username> set default_warehouse = <warehouse name>`